# how to import a map data from firestore in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter and I'm facing some problem with importing a map data stored in firestore back to a flutter app. I succesfully imported a data and some String variables. Also next step after that is to import a List of maps. I want an example about how to import the address and the list of products.

I have this code:

```
Future<void> getOrderDetails(String id) async {
final orderSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('orders')
    .where('Order id', isEqualTo: id)
    .get();
if (orderSnapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
  return;
}
final orderData = orderSnapshot.docs.first.data();
status = orderData['Status'];
print(status);
this.id = id;
print(this.id);
Timestamp t;
t = orderData['Date & Time'];
startDate = t.toDate();
print(startDate);
}
```

Also the firestore database looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the data retrieved from firestore into their respective data structure types.

For example: `"Address"` would be a `Map` of type `<String,dynamic>`.

`"Products"` would be a `List` of `Map<String,dynamic>`, but casting to a `List` of `dynamic` type will work fine.

```dart
Future<void> getOrderDetails(String id) async {
final orderSnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('orders')
    .where('Order id', isEqualTo: id)
    .get();
if (orderSnapshot.docs.isEmpty) {
  return;
}
final orderData = orderSnapshot.docs.first.data();
status = orderData['Status'];
print(status);
this.id = id;
print(this.id);
Timestamp t;
t = orderData['Date & Time'];
startDate = t.toDate();
print(startDate);

//new code below
var addressMap = orderData['address'] as Map<String,dynamic>;
var buildingNum = addressMap['Building Number'];
print('building number: $buildingNum');

var productList = orderData['Products'] as List<dynamic>;
for(var productItemMap in productList){
  print('product name: ${productItemMap['name']}');
}
}
```